# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps crashing

Tags: 18.04, kernel, crash

My Ubuntu machine keeps crashing unexpectedly. I'm not sure how to properly debug this issue, any help would be appreciated. Once it crashes it becomes unresponsive to `REISUB` as well.

Here's the output from `journalctl -b -1 -e`: https://pastebin.com/4N6ZB2L1

Especially notice the:

`ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)`
`ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PR09._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-531)`

and

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check Exception: 5 Bank 2: f200000000000014
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:906ec TIME 1584692094 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode ca
Performance Events: PEBS fmt3+, Skylake events, 32-deep LBR, full-width counters, Broken BIOS detected, complain to your hardware vendor.
[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources (MSR 38d is b0)
```

The specs of my machine:

- Motherboard: Asus PRIME Z390-A
- Processor: Intel Core i9 9900K
- GPU: Gigabyte GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Windforce 11G
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance LPX 32GB DDR4 DIMM 3000 MHz/15 (2x16GB)
- SSD: Samsung 970 EVO 1TB M.2
- Cooling: Corsair Hydro Series H100i RGB Platinum
- Power: Corsair Professional Series HX850

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.4 with the 5.3.0-42-generic kernel.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the system is complaining about the bios. I see that the latest bios version is Version 1401 released on 2019/12/11. Do you have that version installed? If not I would highly recommend trying to update it. You can find the download [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z390-A/HelpDesk_BIOS/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages show that there is an issue with the bios. I see that the latest bios version is 1401 which was released on 12/11/2019.

The release notes state

> Version 1401 2019/12/118.37 MBytes
>
> PRIME Z390-A BIOS 1401
> Improve Memory overclocking rules
> Improved compatibility with the Intel H10 Optane Module
> Fixed an issue that prevented the adjustment of the Tjmax parameter when using an i9-9900KS processor

If this is not the version that you are running then you should update to it. The user manual shows that you can upgrade the bios by either downloading it [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/PRIME-Z390-A/HelpDesk_BIOS/), and then loading it onto a flash drive, or installing it over the internet.

One cool feature of this board is the ability to update the bios over the internet from within the bios itself. Here are the instructions on how to do that as listed by the user manual

> To update the BIOS by Internet:
>
> 1. Enter the Advanced Mode of the BIOS setup program. Go to the Tool menu to select ASUS EZ Flash Utility and press .
> 2. Select by Internet
> 3. Press the Left/Right arrow keys to select an Internet connection method, and then press .
> 4. Follow the onscreen instructions to complete the update.
> 5. Reboot the system when the update process is done

It is always critical that you do not accidentally poweroff the machine during a bios updates or the machine can become unusable. Be sure you have enough time to complete the process before starting.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out. I will let you know if I have more information.

Comment: Just updated my BIOS to the latest version. I had 08/04/2018 installed so that's a quite old one. I will let you know if anything happens.

Comment: Problem seems to be solved didn't get it again.